# iOS Saving managed documents and mocs in dictionaries

Tags: ios, dictionary, null, store

In my main view controller I want to have an NSMutableDictionary to store UIManagedDocuments and MOCs for different directories. For the keys, I'm using the directory NSString names. For some reason when I set a dictionary key, it doesn't add the UIMAnagedDocument or MOC. Here's the code I'm using to set the dictionary (documentName is the NSString of the directory name used in the UIManagedDocument URL):

```
UIManagedDocument *doc = ....

self.managedDocuments[documentName] = doc;
self.managedObjectContexts[documentName] = doc.managedObjectContext;
```

With some NSLog statements I found this:

```
Stored managed document (null)
Stored MOC (null)
```

Here are the NSLog lines:

```
NSLog(@"Stored managed document %@", self.managedDocuments[documentName]);
NSLog(@"Stored MOC %@", self.managedObjectContexts[documentName]);
```

Why are the values not being stored in the dictionary?

**EDIT**

I also just tried storing a simple string

```
self.managedDocuments[documentName] = @"stored string";
```

But I still get the NSlog message

```
Stored managed document (null)
```

I also checked the counts of each dictionary and it appears to be 0 after inserting the data.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. It was so silly. I was just forgetting to instantiate my properties before using them *face palm*